# Trustpilot API not sending invitation e-mails

Tags: php, api

We have an application which is calling the Trustpilot API to send out invitation e-mails to customers so that they can review their recent orders.

Creating the review link etc. works correctly. However, when calling the final step to actually send out the invitation e-mail, the "status" field of the response is always "notsent" and the e-mail is not sent.

The URL is https://invitations-api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/business-units/business_unit_id/invitations

The JSON response is as follows:

```
{
    id: "<response id>",
    businessUnitId: "<business unit id>",
    businessUserId: "<business user id>",
    recipient: {
        name: "<recipient name>",
        email: "<recipient email>"
    },
    referenceId: "<order id>",
    templateId: "<default en-GB template code>",
    locale: "en-GB",
    sender: {
        email: "noreply.invitations@trustpilot.com",
        name: "<client name>"
    },
    replyTo: "noreply.invitations@trustpilot.com",
    createdTime: "2015-04-29T14:34:40.176727Z",
    preferredSendTime: "2015-04-29T14:34:40.176727Z",
    sentTime: null,
    tags: [ ],
    redirectUri: "<trustpilot review url>",
    status: "notsent",
    source: "Kickstart"
}
```

We have not modified the SPF record for the client's domain, so I am using noreply.invitations@trustpilot.com as the sender and reply-to addresses. Additionally, I have set the preferred send time so that the e-mail should be sent straight away. Nothing I do is making any difference.

Can anyone advise what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see `/invitations` api, i only see `/email-invitations`, is this different? Also, I am aware this is an old post XD (https://developers.trustpilot.com/invitation-api)

Comment: Hi @KevinDanikowski - it IS an old post - I'd forgotten about it! Given it's been eight years since I posted it, I imagine they've changed one or two things :)

Comment: actuall your post was a HUGE help! It turns out I have some account bug and couldn't use their actual `/email-invitations` one on the API, but I was able to use this deprecated one and it is working the same. So I appreicate that! I wouldn't have known without this post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out - the reply to address I was specifying was being rejected. Even though it was valid (or when I tried using noreply.invitations...) - I switched to using one that the client has been using themselves and they started sending straight away after that.

Answer (score 0):

The reply-to address should be one of the pre-configured addresses in your B2B account. You can see here: https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/articles/201841237-Sender-Information